# How do I make one user 'own' another user in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So I have the basics setup already.

This is my User model:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110102225945
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                   :integer         primary key
#  email                :string(255)
#  encrypted_password   :string(128)
#  password_salt        :string(255)
#  reset_password_token :string(255)
#  remember_token       :string(255)
#  remember_created_at  :datetime
#  sign_in_count        :integer
#  current_sign_in_at   :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at      :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip   :string(255)
#  last_sign_in_ip      :string(255)
#  created_at           :datetime
#  updated_at           :datetime
#  username             :string(255)
#  f_name               :string(255)
#  l_name               :string(255)
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, and :lockable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :timeoutable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  has_many :stages
  has_many :uploads
  has_many :comments
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :owners,
                  :class_name => "User",
                  :association_foreign_key => "owner_id",
                  :join_table => "ownership"

  def role_symbols
    roles.map do |role|
      role.name.underscore.to_sym
    end
  end  
end
```

My Role model looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20101117094659
#
# Table name: roles
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :users, :through => :assignments
end
```

Assignment Looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20101117094659
#
# Table name: assignments
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#  user_id    :integer
#  role_id    :integer
#

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :role
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I have an ownership table that has `owner_id` and `user_id`.

I have one entry in my table that corresponds to two different users. So my question is, how do I interact with the users/records of that join_table.

I would like to know the following:

- In my rails console, how do I interact with the data in that ownership table? I tried `owner.all`, `Owner.all`, `ownership.all`, `owners.all`, all to no avail. So given that this structure is a bit different than the regular associations, how do I do that?
- In my ERB, how do I list all of 'users' that are associated with the current_user? The way I access the projects associated with the current user is like: `current_user.projects.each do |project|` then I can do `project.name` etc. But not quite sure how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what worked for me (the example is a parent/child relation, but it conceptually is the same as a owner/owned one)

```
# The corresponding table has a parent_id and a child_id columns
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => “User”
  belongs_to :child, :class_name => “User”
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # The user’s parents
  # Get them from the relations where
  # the current user is a child
  has_many :parent_relations,
           :class_name => ‘Relation’,
           :foreign_key => ‘child_id’

  has_many :parents,
           :through => :parent_relations

  # The user’s children
  # Get them from the relations where
  # the current user is a parent
  has_many :children_relations,
           :class_name => ‘Relation’,
           :foreign_key => ‘parent_id’

  has_many :children,
           :through => :children_relations
end
```

In this case, you can use the following in your views

```
- current_user.parents.each do |parent|
  %p= parent.email # Since the parent is a User
```

Hope this helps

Comment: So you created a model called 'Relation' ? Or was all of that in your User model? Including your `class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base` ?

Comment: No, I created the relation model, and the corresponding migration.

Comment: Oh I see what you did here. I think the difference is, although I might be able to use this, is that for yours - each user can have both parents and children right? Whereas with mine, a user can only be either a designer or a client. They can't be both. A client can have many designers, and a designer can have many clients. But a user can't be either designer or client - or both at the same time. How would you tweak your solution given those constraints?

Comment: This solution you gave me is brilliant, btw. Thanks for this. Works like a charm. One more question, how do I create a new `designer` or `client` ?

Comment: I see. In this case, you might want to use single table inheritance (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) to make your Designer and Client class inherit from User ; and split the has_many and define them in the corresponding inherited classes.
This way you can create a designer and a client, and you can use @designer.clients but not @designer.designers

Comment: Ok but based on your current model, how do I create a new parent or child? Do I have to create a controller for it, or do I use the User controller?

Comment: For single table inheritance, I think it is best to use the common user ressource. Just replace User with Designer or Client where needed.